# Datetime with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m having this project LIVE on my website in which users can vote.
 now the voting is closing on mid-night 31st of this month. I do not want to delete any of my code for security and add some code to compare the current dates with the date mentioned above. if on 1st of Sep 00:00:01 , user clicks on vote button, i would like to display a message saying that the voting is closed.

I am using Jquery Dialog currently for voting, so i can hide the div contents and show another div contents for voting closed message.

can anyone help please.

thanks

I am trying this way

```
var now = new Date();
            var datetime = now.getFullYear() + '/' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + now.getDay();
            datetime += ' ' + now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds(); 

OUTPUT is: Tue Aug 27 2013 17:08:47 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

I don't know how can i compare this one with the date on which voting is closed.

Comment: you realize, that javascript gets date from the user PC, so if someone set's the date to 3 days back - they will still be able to vote?

Comment: "What have you tried" ... people aren't here to write your code for you.

Comment: @tborychowski hmmm... i will have to try another solution then.

Comment: @patel.milanb You can still do this in JS but you should also add another validation on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Q9Jq3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    eventTime = Date.parse('31 August 2013') / 1000;

    function time_until() {
        currentTime = Math.floor(jQuery.now() / 1000);

        seconds = eventTime - currentTime;

        days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24));
        $('#time').html('seconds ' + seconds + '<br/>days ' + days);
    }
    setInterval(time_until,1000)
});
```

for you code

```
function time_until() {
            currentTime = Math.floor(jQuery.now() / 1000);

            seconds = eventTime - currentTime;
            if(second == 0){
                   //Stop voting
            }

            days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24));
            $('#time').html('seconds ' + seconds + '<br/>days ' + days);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple comparison should work:

```
var sep1 = +new Date('2013-09-01T00:00:00'),  // "+" operator will return unix timestamp
    now = +new Date();

if (now >= sep1) {
    // too late to vote
}
else {
    // you can vote
}
```